# UnicodeDecodeError: Utf-8 Decode Error while parsing Midi File

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, midi, audio-player, music21

I was trying to parse a few music files using music21, but the code is generating utf-8 error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Here is my code:

```
notes = []
for file in glob.glob("midi_songs/*.mid"):
print("parsing %s"%file)
midi = converter.parse(file)

elements_to_parse = midi.flat.notes
for ele in elements_to_parse:
    #Note: Store Pitch
    if isinstance(ele, note.Note):
        notes.append(str(ele.pitch))


    #Chorde: Split note and join
    elif isinstance(ele, chord.Chord):
        notes.append("+".join(str(n) for n in ele.normalOrder))
```

#### Traceback

[image: Error Message generated py the python kernel]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ca5986c7b6d6> in <module>
      2 for file in glob.glob("midi_songs/*.mid"):
      3     print("parsing %s"%file)
----> 4     midi = converter.parse(file)
      5 
      6     elements_to_parse = midi.flat.notes
```

Comment: Can you check the indentation of your code?

Comment: Try changing your encoding to something like ISO-8859-1 because it supports most number of symbol and characters

Comment: Looks like a bug in music21.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression in music21 6.1.0 that was fixed in 6.3.0

Each problematic file we found to have a copyright symbol in the track name message and was written by [www.piano-midi.de](http://www.piano-midi.de).